# Visual Studio Bracket Colorization

Tags: colors, brackets, visual-studio-2022

Is there a free bracket colorization extension compatible with VS 2022 and Windows Pro 10 OS? I used Viasfora with VS 2019 but it is not yet available with VS 2022. I checked free Extension options in *Manage Extensions*, and as far as I can see there isn't one, but I am hoping I am wrong. In Managed Extensions I found a tool called *IndentRainbow*, but it adds color to indented space, not to brackets. I googled Bracket Pair Colorizer but it is not available as a VS 2022 extension, and I am not able to install it from its site - when I click *Install* nothing happens.

Comment: In previous versions I've used Viasfora, but port to 2022 is not yet in place.

Answer (score 13):

There is a fork of the Viasfora repo with a .vsix that works with VS2022 [here](https://github.com/IllyaTheHath/viasfora/releases/tag/vs17) - it seems to work well and not found any issues with it so far.

It is possible that Tomas Restrepo the creator of Viasfora will [create an official fix](https://github.com/tomasr/viasfora/issues/314) for his great extension.

Comment: I found this extension id disabling tooltips in VS. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 5):

As of [17.6.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.6#1761--visual-studio-2022-version-1761) this is supported (it was previously added in earlier preview builds of Visual Studio, but this version adds official support).

Release notes:

> You can enable or disable colorization by going to Tools > Options > Text Editor and toggling the "Enable brace pair colorization" checkbox.

[image: image showing the enabled brace pair colorization checkbox]

After enabling this, all matching braces/parentheses/brackets should be color matched:

[image: example image showing the colored brackets]

Comment: Thanks. It was in 17.5 preview 3 (and 17.6 preview 1) but was removed in the final 17.5 release and is now planned for 17.6 per https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/bracket-pair-colorization-feature-does-n/10287569

Comment: @AndrewD.Bond of course they didn't update their patch notes. I use the preview version (17.6 preview), and just assumed that 17.5 was good to go. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the **Rainbow Braces**: https://github.com/madskristensen/RainbowBraces with Visual Studio 2022 Professional and Windows 11.

Comment: Can someone confirm if the 'new' baked in Visual Studio functionality "Enable brace pair colorization" replaces this extension?